# Why we need a carriage return \r before the new line character \n?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, newline, carriage-return

In the following code the HTTP protocol needs two newline character but what is the need of the \r there. Why can't we just add two \n and send the request?

```
import socket
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(("data.pr4e.org",80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode() # here
mysock.send(cmd)
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) > 0:
        print(data.decode())
    else :
        break
mysock.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's how [the HTTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945) is defined. More specifically, HTTP 1.0 defines a request [like this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#page-23):

```
Request        = Simple-Request | Full-Request

Full-Request   = Request-Line             
                 *( General-Header       
                  | Request-Header      
                  | Entity-Header )    
                 CRLF
                 [ Entity-Body ]
 
Request-Line = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF
```

`Full-Request`, which is what should be used by any HTTP 1.0 compatible client (simple request is HTTP 0.9 and deprecated) needs to have two `CRLF` tokens (one is in `Request-Line`). A `CRLF` token is the two bytes `\r\n`. Hence the need to end the string in your example with `\r\n\r\n`.

This design choice was kept in HTTP 1.1.

Comment: How does telnet send a CRLF only by entering enter twice?

Comment: @ChetanNaik telnet automatically translates `\n` to `\r\n` for you under the hood. The same can be done with the `-C` option for `netcat`.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is how the HTTP protocol works.

> The request/status line and headers must all end with `<CR><LF>` (that is, a carriage return followed by a line feed). The empty line must consist of only `<CR><LF>` and no other whitespace.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_message_body